# TensorFlow tutorials Training model with less images than expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

challenge refers to TensorFlow tutorials like:

(1) https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification

or (2) https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn

In (1) there is paragraph *"Feed the model"* https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification#feed_the_model where output says in each epoch `60000 / 60000`.

In (2) there is *"Compile and train the model"* https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn#compile_and_train_the_model where output says `50000 / 50000`.

In both cases it corresponds with number of images in training datasets.

When I run these tutorials in Google Colab:

(1) https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/keras/classification.ipynb

(2) https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/images/cnn.ipynb

out of the box, without any modifications, I can only get `1875 / 1875` for (1) and `1563 / 1563` for (2).

Any magic behind?
Perhaps known issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have completed this challenge.
When you look at `model.fit()` you will see explanation for `batch_size` as follows:

```
batch_size: Integer or `None`.
If unspecified, `batch_size` will default to 32.
```

And it finds confirmation in both (1) and (2) tutorials:

(1) `60000 / 32 = 1875`

(2) `50000 / 32 = 1563` (rounded up)

So `model.fit()` in case of these tutorials shows progress in batch numbers, not in image numbers as I initially thought